# Android Studio: Show android source and javadoc

Tags: android, android-studio

How can you see the Android source code in Android Studio?

It worked in some versions, but currently I'm not able to see it. Additionally, to show Android javadoc it actually connects to developers.android.com (which is painfully slow) instead of showing local javadoc.

I already have the documentation and sources installed in SDK Manager, and under Project Structure -> Platform Settings there's no way to attach sources or javadoc like before, now it just shows two properties: Android SDK location and JDK location. That's all. Extra good karma if you can tell me how to see the source/javadoc of support libraries, which never has worked at all.

I'm using Android Studio 0.4.3 and JDK 1.7.

Comment: Check this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21221679/android-studio-how-to-attach-android-sdk-sources/21221907#21221907

Comment: I already have the sources and javadoc for the android version specified in targetSdk, so it doesn't work

Comment: Which API you are using, let me give a try at my environment.

Comment: @ScottBarta your linked response works perfect, thanks