# How to browse android SDK sources in Android studio 2.0

Tags: android, android-studio

I know this question was asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21221679/android-studio-how-to-attach-android-sdk-sources) and an good post [here](https://plus.google.com/+CyrilMottier/posts/hpeR2eaD33k). But none of the given solutions seem to work in android studio 2.0. can someone please point out how to browse the android SDK sources in android studio 2.0?

Comment: Which preview version are you in? It seems to be working fine with my Android Studio 2.1 preview 3 version. Just for double-checking, which compileSdkVersion are you using in your module's build.gradle file?

Comment: I'm using using preview version 6 and compile SDK version 23

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't pickup automatically ;

- Control+ Click Framework Class (Should show you decompiled code)
- Choose Sources..
- Point to  ~\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\sources\android-23

Comment: When I select a framework class the decompiled class shows the code of mock android.  In which in which all methods are overridden to throw RuntimeException("stub!");

Comment: You should see the "Decompiled.class file" banner. Click "Choose Sources.." on the top right hand corner of the banner.

Comment: it shows the source of MockableAndroid.jar not the real android source