# My android studio debugger is off by a couple of lines

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio

When I run debugger, some files (but not all files) the line that is highlighted is not actually the line being run. This makes debugging a bit confusing. I'd be ok if it always happened or never happened but with this happening sometimes and not other times, it's really hard to find the bug. 
[image: about android studio version]
[image: example debugger]
You can see above that the line highlighted is in `newArray(...)` but given the variable details at the bottom, it is clearly running in the middle of `public static Parcel obtain()`.

This seems to only happen to files that I have not made like `Parcel.java`, but not all the time. Also, you can see in the example that there is red which marks error. This also happens when the app runs without error so I don't know why those appear. That's probably a separate question though.

And my gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mattermost.mattermost"
        minSdkVersion 19

        /* If you want to change targetSdkVersion to higher version, please make sure you
         * convert application icon to meet desired lollipop guidelines, that is icon should be
         * flat and white*/
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 306
        versionName "3.0.6"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/services/com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory'
    }
}
```

Comment: `Clean, Rebuild and Run` it again

Comment: What is your compile SDK? And what is the API level of your emulator/device?

Answer (score 0):

Did you attach the correct sources to you environment? I can see that you are using the sources of android-23 (Android 6.0), is that what your target device is running?

Comment: Added my gradle file, I am running on a physical devce with android version 4.4.2 and api 19. Shouldn't it be able to run on any device with api 19-23?

Comment: Well the soures are a view of what is being executed. You should download sources for android-19 and attach those instead in your debug environment, then I think the lines would match.

Comment: Are you talking about when I open the SDK manager? I have SDK Platforms from 4.1 to 6.0 all downloaded.

Comment: No, I'm talking about the sources you have setup in Android Studio. They are setup to android-23. Look at this link how to change to point at the right sources http://stackoverflow.com/a/36903786/626741