# How to get sources for Android 7.1.1 (Nougat)?

Tags: android, android-studio

At the of writing, there is no option to download **Sources for Android 25**:

[image]

Does it not have released yet? Or my SDK manager is broken?

Comment: "Does it not have released yet?" -- perhaps not. 7.1.1 is only rolling out to devices starting today (except the Pixel and Pixel XL, which shipped with it). The tools team may have been waiting for 7.1.1 to ship before packaging API Level 25 source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SDK 25 sources are now available for download in the SDK manager. After downloading you might need to [refresh the SDK with this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21221679/android-studio-how-to-attach-android-sdk-sources/36903786#36903786) to make Android Studio aware of them.