# getChildCount() in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragmentstatepageradapter

I'm trying to understand how viewpager works by breaking down the source and I got to the dataSetChanged method. I got to the **dataSetChanged** method and within it is this piece of code.

```
if (needPopulate) {
     // Reset our known page widths; populate will recompute them.
     final int childCount = getChildCount();
     for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
          final View child = getChildAt(i);
          final LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
          if (!lp.isDecor) {
              lp.widthFactor = 0.f;
          }
     }
}
```

I was wondering what is it that `getChildCount()` returns when it is called. I understand that it is a `ViewGroup` method and returns all the children of the `Viewgroup` calling the method but in this instance would the method return 1 for the `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` that I will be adding or does it return the number of pages within my `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`? What is the best way to find out?

Comment: Why don't you just debug your code ?

Comment: I guess that's what I'm trying to figure out. How do you debug the classes that come from android? Sorry if this is a very amateur question.

Comment: you'll need to download the sources in SDK manager

Comment: I think I did. That's the way I was trying to decompose the viewpager source. I had to manually navigate to ~/Library/Android/...etc. to look at the source. I know there is an easier way using the debug tools in Android Studio but I just haven't reached that point yet. I was hoping to get there with this post.

Comment: If you have the source then while debugging your app you should be able to step into the source code. Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36903786/1630255

Comment: Awesome, I think that gives me what I'm looking for. I'll come back and answer my own question now that I can follow exactly what it is doing. Thank you @Neeraj

Comment: For my case getChildCount() was 2. It created two children. prior to getting to this method.