# InAppropriate names of parameter in implemented/overrided methods

Tags: java, android, parameters, kotlin, parameter-passing

I am using android studio 3.0.1 and i am developing android application using kotlin. so, i have configured kotlin in my project. After configuring kotlin when i override any methods, i am getting the parameter names as p0, p1, p2, etc as below.

```
override fun query(p0: Uri?, p1: Array<out String>?, p2: String?, p3: Array<out String>?, p4: String?): Cursor {
    ...
}
```

Instead of these names i want appropriate names of parameters like projection, selection, selectionArgs, etc as below.

```
public Cursor query(@NonNull Uri uri, @Nullable String[] projection, @Nullable String selection, @Nullable String[] selectionArgs, @Nullable String sortOrder) {
    ...
}
```

when i was using java it was working fine but when i started using kotlin this problem occures. This parameter names are confusing. so, i want to get names like i get in java code. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: If you open that base class containing `query`, AS should provide an option to "download sources"

Comment: every time i have to open base class for watching parameters. is there any better way? when i open base class AS is not providing me option to "download sources". it just open base class. @s1m0nw1

Comment: Maybe this helps then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21221679/android-studio-how-to-attach-android-sdk-sources