# Incorrect variable names in overridden methods

Tags: java, android, kotlin, overriding

When I let Android Studio generate override method it will generate the method with strange parameter names.

For instance according to documentation onCheckedChanged should look like this:

```
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked){}
```

but i got

```
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b){}
```

or onDateSet in DatePickerDialog i got:

```
onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int i, int i1, int i2)
```

instead of

```
onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth)
```

I got Android SDK set up in a project and Sources for Android 27 installed.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: it`s variable Names  , does it`s Matter ?!

Comment: possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48008103/inappropriate-names-of-parameter-in-implemented-overrided-methods)

Comment: @Elsunhoty it REALLY does matter.  If you take a good look at the example `onDateSet`, you can see that 3 integers mean **nothing** while meaningful names do tell you precisely what each parameter represents. I'm very curios to find a solution for this, cause I've had it bother me for a while! I know some methods used to have good parameter names, and they just tend to stop.

Comment: Yes , Your are Right

Answer (score 26):

It is related to the `compileSdkVersion` which is defined in your `build.gradle` file. You should install `Sources for Android SDK` for the API you used as `compileSdkVersion`. So try to install sources version equal to `compileSdkVersion` in SDK Manager.

I've set the `compileSdkVersion 28` in `build.gradle` file. Here is the result before and after installing sources version 28 (Notice: You should restart AndroidStudio after that):

**Before:**

```
val textWatcher = object: TextWatcher {

    override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {
    }

    override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
    }

    override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
    }
}
```

**After:**

```
val textWatcher = object: TextWatcher {

    override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
    }

    override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
    }

    override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
    }
}
```

---

### *UPDATE: 10/23/2018*

The problem about **AppCompat-v28** libraries such as `RecyclerView` class, comes from their `aar` artifacts. If you use version 27.1.1 libraries, the issue will gone. It doesn't matter what distribution of version 28 you are using (Such as 28.0.0, 28.0.0-alpha1, 28.0.0-alpha3, 28.0.0-rc1, 28.0.0-rc2, etc.) In all of version 28 distributions, the parameter names for abstract methods are obfuscated.

```
public abstract static class Adapter<VH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    public Adapter() {
    }

    @NonNull
    public abstract VH onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup var1, int var2);

    public abstract void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull VH var1, int var2);

    ...
}
```

So it seems that there is no way to solve, until it would be fixed in the next distributions.

Comment: Yes, the above example also works in my case but when i try to create **RecyclerView's Adapter** and override the **onCreateViewHolder(p0: ViewGroup, p1: Int)** method it still shows incorrect arguments variable names.

Comment: thanks for the update :) Hope Android dev team will notice and fix this

Comment: Such a great answer!

Comment: Thank you for saving my time . I was trying to understand why my `FirebaseMessagingService` has such weird name on Overriding methods.

Answer (score 7):

As aminography said, this is because you have not installed sources for `compileSdk` you are using.
For installing sources follow this steps:

1. check your project's compileSdk version.(from app level `build.gradle` file). As you can see in below image my compileSdk version is 26. So, i have to install sources for platform 26.

[image]

2.
Go to sdk manager and in SDK Platforms tab check `show package details` option if not checked. Then install sources for your compileSdk version(In my case it's 26). That's it. Now, you will get appropriate parameters name.

[image]