# is it possible to prevent kotlin from changing parameter names in functions in implemented interfaces?

Tags: android, kotlin

is it possible to prevent kotlin from changing parameter names in functions in  implemented interfaces ?
for example in this implemented spinner AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener:

kotlin changes default parameter names :

```
 parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View, position: Int, id: Long
```

to

```
p0: AdapterView<*>?, p1: View?, p2: Int, p3: Long


spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
        override fun onItemSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?, p1: View?, p2: Int, p3: Long) {
        }

        override fun onNothingSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?) {

        }
    }
```

i know it's because kotlin trying to decrease java boilerplate code but sometimes it makes code becomes confusing.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49219439/incorrect-variable-names-in-overridden-methods, it may help.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov thank you for sharing that question, i installed sources for my compiled sdk version  and now it's fixed