# How to setup and debug a SDK api such as EditText from android source?

Tags: android, sdk, android-edittext, android-source

I have a issue with how edittext is responding in certain conditions. Is there a way to include actual AOSP code in your build of an app to be able to actually debug the code in the edittext api, as it is normally stubbed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this answer for details how to add android SDK sources to android studio
[Android Studio: how to attach Android SDK sources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21221679/android-studio-how-to-attach-android-sdk-sources)