# Sources for android API 32 platform not found

Tags: android, android-studio

[image][image][image]It says

> sources for android API 32 platform not found

and when I try to download it say

> all packages are not available for download

how can I solve this problem ?[image]

Comment: Download it from android Sdk section in settings

Comment: I did and nothing changed

Comment: try those solutions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21221679/android-studio-how-to-attach-android-sdk-sources

Comment: unfortunately nothing changed

Comment: Can you show your selections in the Android sdk section?

Comment: of course, here you are, i edit the question and added sdk section

Comment: Please, show with "Show package details" selected

Comment: Sorry for the delay, here you are, i edit the question and added what you want

Comment: API 32 seems to be too recent. If the sources aren't listed in the packages list it means it's not released yet.

Comment: should i delete API 32 ?

Comment: Unless you really need it, i'd stick to the latest public released version. In this case latest public is API 31. For API 32 there's only a developer preview.

Comment: According to Google's SDK Platform release notes page, API 32 is released. Still no sources though.