# LazyListScope.item() : syntax explanation

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Out of curiosity, I was trying to understand the inner workings of function items() in this code :

```kotlin
 LazyColumn(
    ) {
        items(dogs) {
            DogItem(dog = it)
        }
    }
```

The source gives us :

```kotlin
inline fun <T> LazyListScope.items(
    items: List<T>,
    noinline key: ((item: T) -> Any)? = null,
    noinline contentType: (item: T) -> Any? = { null },
    crossinline itemContent: @Composable LazyItemScope.(item: T) -> Unit
) = items(
    count = items.size,
    key = if (key != null) { index: Int -> key(items[index]) } else null,
    contentType = { index: Int -> contentType(items[index]) }
) {
    itemContent(items[it])
}
```

When I go to the source of `items()`, I get :

```kotlin
    fun items(
        count: Int,
        key: ((index: Int) -> Any)? = null,
        contentType: (index: Int) -> Any? = { null },
        itemContent: @Composable LazyItemScope.(index: Int) -> Unit
    ) {
        error("The method is not implemented")
    }
```

1. The following syntax with the `=` sign is a [single-expression function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/functions.html#single-expression-functions), right ?

```kotlin
fun LazyListScope.items() = items(...){...}
```

2. The `{...}` after `items(...)` is the trailing lambda of the `items()` function, right ?
3. So we are passing the trailing lambda "`{itemContent(item[it])}`" to the `items(...)` function.  But where `items()` is implemented ? If we go to the source of `items(...)`, its body is `error : not implemented`. So what will be executed ? What does the function `items()` do ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The following syntax with the = sign is a single-expression function, right ?

Right, that is exactly a single expression function.

> The {...} after items(...) is the trailing lambda of the items() function, right ?

Yes, that is the [trailing lambda syntax](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#passing-trailing-lambdas), since the last parameter of `items()` function is a function. [Here is the signature](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/LazyListScope#items(kotlin.Int,kotlin.Function1,kotlin.Function1,kotlin.Function2)) for you to verify.

> The {...} after items(...) is the trailing lambda of the items() function, right ?

The source code and particular implementation can be found [in this artifact](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.compose.foundation/foundation-layout/1.2.0-beta03). The exact reason why you are unable to view the source code from IDE might be becuase the Android Studio is unable to locate the implementation for `LazyListScope` ([Here is the implementation](https://androidx.tech/artifacts/compose.foundation/foundation/1.2.0-beta03-source/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/LazyListScopeImpl.kt.html) if you need it) - there is no source for given artifact loaded, I guess that might be the problem. But it is just a guessing, it might be different, hard to say from outside.

At least hope it helped, have a nice day :)

Comment: Thank you very much. I edited main post to add source of `items()` (when I press F4 on `items()` in Android Studio).


So how can the code be executed with `error("The method is not implemented")` as body of the `items()` function ?

Also, do you have an idea how I could make Android Studio find the proper source ?

Comment: To be honest I think you should better ask another question about how to attach source code to androidx libs :) This is a bit differnt question and it requires its own discussion. Maybe this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21221679/android-studio-how-to-attach-android-sdk-sources
I suggest you to either try anwsers there or create your own question :)

Comment: Thank you, question has been asked here : https://stackoverflow.com/q/78096765/13962899.