# Body of a function found in the source is : "error("The method is not implemented")". Why?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

Out of curiosity, I was looking at source of `items()` in this code using Jetpack Compose elements (pressing F4 in Android Studio) :

```kotlin
 LazyColumn(
    ) {
        items(dogs) {
            DogItem(dog = it)
        }
    }
```

So by going to `items()` source, I get :

```kotlin
inline fun <T> LazyListScope.items(
    items: List<T>,
    noinline key: ((item: T) -> Any)? = null,
    noinline contentType: (item: T) -> Any? = { null },
    crossinline itemContent: @Composable LazyItemScope.(item: T) -> Unit
) = items(
    count = items.size,
    key = if (key != null) { index: Int -> key(items[index]) } else null,
    contentType = { index: Int -> contentType(items[index]) }
) {
    itemContent(items[it])
}
```

However, when going to `items()` source, I get :

```kotlin
   fun items(
        count: Int,
        key: ((index: Int) -> Any)? = null,
        contentType: (index: Int) -> Any? = { null },
        itemContent: @Composable LazyItemScope.(index: Int) -> Unit
    ) {
        error("The method is not implemented")
    }
```

1. How can the code be executed if the body of the source has `error("The method is not implemented")` in it ?
2. If the wrong source is shown by Android Studio : why ? And how to make Android Studio display the "real" source ?
3. What is the purpose of this `items()` function with `error("The method is not implemented")` as body ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The `items()` function you're looking at is an `inline` function that is part of the LazyListScope interface. Inline functions in Kotlin are (iirc) expanded at compile time, which means the function's code is inserted directly into the calling code. This process can sometimes complicate navigation through the source code in Android Studio, you will run into similar examples often (the most popualr being [RuntimeException("Stub!")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39913574/meaning-of-runtimeexceptionstub-in-android))

When you navigate to the source of an inline function, you might see the placeholder `error("The method is not implemented")` because the actual implementation is not present in the compiled bytecode that Android Studio navigates through. Instead, the implementation is part of the Kotlin compiler's output, which is not directly viewable in Android Studio's source code view.

Comment: Thank you very much : So is there a common method to track down the "real" source ? Is there a way to know which code will finally be executed ? It must be written somewhere ? How come this can't be found in the sources ?

Comment: Usually we just google stuff like `LazyListScope.items()` and find this: 
https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/LazyListScope#items(kotlin.Int,kotlin.Function1,kotlin.Function1,kotlin.Function2)
and there is a button at the top to view the source